# BotFramework Dispatch Model: Automate the Dispatch Command Line tool

Tags: npm, command-line, botframework, azure-language-understanding, command-line-tool

I implemented a [dispatch bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs) using LUIS and QnA Maker, .NET SDK V4.

On my local folder, I run the [dispatch refresh command line](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch) to update my LUIS application whenever I add a pair of question/answer in my QnA service.

My goal is to automate this process: I want to schedule the command `dispatch refresh --dispatch file.dispatch` to run every day.

My dispatch bot is hosted on Azure DevOps. 
I just want to run the command independently from the build process.

How can I do this ? Is there a way we can automate this without using the Azure DevOps pipelines ?

Comment: Are you wanting to run this everyday on your own machine or on the machine where the repository is hosted? Is there any reason for not wanting to use Azure DevOps pipelines - is it that you don't want to use ADO pipelines at all or are you trying to avoid having it part of the same build pipeline?

Comment: I want it to run on the machine where the repository is hosted but I don't want it to be dependent to the build pipeline that's why I don't want to use Azure DevOps.

Comment: You could have a separate pipeline associated with the repo in Azure DevOps that just runs the dispatch command on a schedule or check in trigger (or both). Otherwise if you completely want an outside Azure DevOps you're looking at writing something like an Azure Logic App, Azure Function, or Windows Service.